# SQL. Выбрать пользователей не отправляющих отчеты последние 2 дня в текущем месяце

Tags: sql

[image: Таблица]

Прошу помощи с составлением sql-запроса. Сегодня 3 ноября и мне нужно вывести ID менеджера который не присылал отчеты последние 2 дня подряд в текущем месяце (1 и 2 ноября этот отчет пуст, в предыдущий месяц смотреть не нужно).

Задача максимально упрощена, в реальном проекте 4 таблицы с 2 join'ами

```
SELECT user_id, user_first_name, user_last_name 
FROM USERS
WHERE user_id NOT IN (
    SELECT 
        user_id FROM REPORTS 
        WHERE user_id IN (
           SELECT 
           user_id FROM REPORTS 
           WHERE date >= '2020-11-01'
        )
)
```

Не работает.

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT users.*
FROM users
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM reports
                   WHERE users.user_id = reports.user_id
                     AND reports.`date` > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 DAY )
```

PS. Использован синтаксис MySQL. Для другой СУБД - откорректировать выражение вычисления пограничной даты.